# How split div background into 'n' color bands with CSS

Tags: css

I have a large table, and need to change the background of a cell to be 1 to 6 color bands, like rectangle stacked on top of each other (and other information will appear within the cell).  While this example is a table, I'm guessing this applies to any DIV.  I'd like to be able (via javascript on the fly) grab the 'cellcontainer' DIV in the DOM and create children DIV's to create a banded background effect.

```
<table border=1 width=400 height=400>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="cellcontainer">
                One
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For this simple table, I'm trying to take the first cell (with div 'cellcontainer') and make the background three different colors, like light blue, yellow, and green.  I've tried adding children divs with height=33%, and setting cellcontainer's style to relative and children divs to absolute, etc.  but I haven't found the magic combination.

Comment: What non-magic combination have You found? (Questions like this are like 'do it for me')

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. If the three "color bands" are meant as containers for different kinds of data (which I gather from your "and other information will appear"), you should make them table cells! Otherwise, yes, a linear-gradient.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to make the background of the cell 3 different colours, do you mean a gradient? If so try [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

else I'm not too sure what you mean by "make the background 3 different colours".

Comment: These will be table cells, with each cell having a DIV with a unique ID.  And not a gradient, but 'n' color bands for the background color.  Terribly mocked up example:  [link](http://imgur.com/9MBb0)

Comment: Oh, and further subdividing the table cell with rowspan or embedding another table in the cell would interfere with the display of normal cell data.

Comment: I did it using the site i provided and split it up into the 3 colours you stated in a non-gradient style. Try this:

background: linear-gradient(top, #31eff9 33%,#edff30 33%,#edff30 66%,#00c100 66%);

Comment: Lodder, great suggestion, and I did get gradients working, but as you know gradients are supported inconsistently across browsers, and I couldn't get it to work at all for iPhone or Android browsers (well, only partially on Firefox, not on the built in browser or Chrome).

Is there any method to subdivide a table cell into stacked divs or something that is supported across browsers?